# Exception with Federation Connectivity Test

Tags: tomcat, adfs2.0, openam, federation

When I am trying to run the Federation Connectivity Test from my openam with the ADFS server configured am getting the following exception:

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: AMSetupFilter.doFilter
    com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:117)
root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:541)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:435)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:91)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.validator_jsp._jspService(validator_jsp.java:424)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:91)

I think got stucked up due to this exception and the connection with the adfs is not getting setup. So should I go about it.

Any sort of help will be useful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

On OpenAM side set debug level to 'message' and have a look into the debug logs. There should be a pointer for the NPE, possibly missing certificate alias or insufficient MetaData.

Comment: I have just added the sp.xml and ipd.xml generated from opemam & adfs respectively. Then how should i go about it and solve the problem